Regular expression to match contents of double brackets containing other groups of double brackets
I would like to clean-up raw data from a Wiktionary dump.
Here are two usecases.
Multilines:
[[Archivo:Diagrama bicicleta.svg|400px|miniaturadeimagen|'''Partes de una bicicleta:'''<br>
[[asiento]] o [[sillín]], [[cuadro]]{{-sub|8}}, [[potencia]], [[puño]]{{-sub|4}}, [[cuerno]], [[manubrio]], [[telescopio]], [[horquilla]], [[amortiguador]], [[frenos]], [[tijera]], [[rueda]], [[rayos]], [[buje]], [[llanta]], [[cubierta]], [[válvula]], [[pedal]], [[viela]], [[cambio]], [[plato]]{{-sub|5}} o [[estrella]], [[piñón]], [[cadena]], [[tija]], [[tubo de asiento]], [[vaina]].]] + [[ something|of course]]

Single line:
[[File:Karwats.jpg|thumb|A scourge ''(noun {{senseno|en|whip}})'' [[exhibit#Verb|exhibited]] in a [[museum#Noun|museum]].]] + [[ something|of course]]

In both cases, I need to match only what is inside [[Archivo:xxx]] and [[File:xxx]] where both can be multilines statement, and include nested double-bracket code that need to go away too.
It's not my first attempt haha, I retry on a regular basis, but I can't make it work alone!
Here is my current regexp, which will match the whole line (and in both examples, the regexp should leave alone the trailing  + [[ something|of course]]).
\[\[(?:Archivo|File):(?:.|\n)+?(?=\]\])\]\]$


Note: I can produce some code without using a regexp, but meh, it would be shorter to find that magic pattern!

can you please say what your desired output for the two cases would be?

The desired output is  " + [[ something|of course]]"

You could write your own parser, or use a recursive pattern https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-balanced-parentheses and for Python use the PyPi regex module https://pypi.org/project/regex/

You cannot do this with classic re but as Thefourthbird noted there are libraries supporting recursive expressions. IMO it would be easier/faster to write a state machine to parse these

All depend how many nested levels you have, if you have only one nested level of double brackets, you can do it with re and an appropriate pattern. For more levels, follow the suggestions in previous comments (regex engine with recursion capabilities or your own parser).

@CasimiretHippolyte Thanks! It works like a charm. Two notes: could you add your comment as an answer so that I can mark the question solved? And there is a scenario not covered by the regexp (I forgot to mention it though, and it's OK to not fix it if that's too complex): this text should be matched entirely: "[[Archivo:Mezquita de Córdoba - Celosía 006.JPG|thumb|[1]]]".

@Tiger-222 Does my solution below help or should it be removed?

Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, I'll be able to test in a couple of hours. Out of curiosity, does you version handle the usecase in my last comment?

That is why  I posted as an answer. It should handle all these cases.

Based on this Casimir's comment, I have come up with this pattern that also accounts for numbers inside square brackets:
\[\[(?:Archivo|File):[^][]*(?:](?!])[^][]*|\[(?!\[|\d+\])[^][]*)*(?:(?:\[\d+\]|\[\[[^][]*(?:](?!])[^][]*|\[(?!\[)[^][]*)*\]\])[^][]*(?:](?!])[^][]*|\[(?!\[|\d+\])[^][]*)*)*]]

See the regex demo.
Details:

\[\[ - matches [[
(?:Archivo|File): - Archivo: or File:
[^][]*(?:](?!])[^][]*|\[(?!\[|\d+\])[^][]*)* - this matches any chars other than [ and ], or any ] that is not immediately followed with another ], or a [ that is not immediately followed with [ or one or more digits + ]
(?:(?:\[\d+\]|\[\[[^][]*(?:](?!])[^][]*|\[(?!\[)[^][]*)*\]\])[^][]*(?:](?!])[^][]*|\[(?!\[|\d+\])[^][]*)*)* - this matches zero or more occurrences of either [+digit(s)+], or strings between [[ and ]] and then any chars other than [ and ], or any ] that is not immediately followed with another ], or a [ that is not immediately followed with [ or one or more digits + ]
]] - a ]] string.


Perfect, that covers all usecases. Thank you very much Wiktor!
